# What kind of beings are the three women that hunt down the istar

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-rings-of-power

In the Amazon Prime Series, there are three magical beings clad in grey that hunt down one of the main characters and have several interactions with what are to become hobbits.

As shown in the last episode, they

> mistake the istar that presumably is going to be Gandalf for Sauron and offer their service.

They seem to have a strong link to the spirit world and maybe are wraiths. They (well, at least their leader) also show a clear affiliation to the element of fire, so maybe that is a hint.

When they are banished, the Stranger shouts the following:

> From Shadow, you came. To Shadow, I bid you return.

And then, this happens:

[image: the three being banished]

From the [Time](https://time.com/6221970/the-rings-of-power-three-witches/) we know that the makers disclosed the following on the leader of the three *even before the show started*:

> Her character is traveling from far to the east—from the lands of Rhûn.

**Question**: Is there any more definite indication, either by existing lore or disclosed by the makers of the show, to what they actually are?

Comment: Minor Maiar of Nienna? She dressed in gray, which is presumably where Gandalf got the idea.

Comment: @Adamant I would not understand why Maiar of Nienna would be able to form and use fire. There is a clear affiliation to the element

Comment: @Phillip - Well, Gandalf was also a Maia of Nienna, basically, and he was also associated with fire. Of course, Sauron was a Maia of Aulë, the Vala of smithing, and so other Maiar of Aulë would tend to have more association with fire, but gray is not really Sauron or Aulë's color.

Comment: Arien, the spirit of the Sun, was also associated with fire, and there were various Maiar of fire that went over to the service of Melkor, many of which became the Balrogs. But I think even at that point Balrogs were rather more intimidating (notably non-human) in form.

Comment: They are the moths that Gandalf talks to in the PJ films.

Comment: @ibid I had the same idea at the end of the scene but that does not tell us the nature of their fea

Comment: When the meteor man kicks their ass, the spirit form into which those three are momentarily transmuted is exactly the same as the spirit form used for the ringwraiths in the LotR movies by PJ. Of course in the series it seems (?) that Sauron has not yet even crafted the nine rings, but it would not be the only anachronism of the series if those three were supposed to be ringwraiths.

Comment: @Adamant I'll bet they were Balrogs. It's never said whether Balrogs could choose a form or not.  Gandalf was associated with fire because of his Ring.

Comment: I think that by the end of Season 2 (which is well over a year from now) more 'in show' material may be available to answer this question.  Adar's exposition on the spirit world in terms of what Sauron was trying to accomplish up in the North is a hint in that direction, but there's not enough meat on that bone to make an answer.